# A variant of the exponential integral

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, exponential-function, special-functions

Consider the following integral (for $x,y\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$)
$$E(x,y) =  \int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-x/s-ys}}{s}\,\mathrm{d}s,$$
which is a variant of the [usual exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) $E_1(x)$ to which it reduces when $y=0$.

I am interested in the *efficient evaluation* of $E(x,y)$, either by numerical or analytical means. One example would be e.g. a series representation; to give an example, consider expansion around $|ys|\ll 1$, which yields a series representation in generalized exponential integrals $E_n(x)$
\begin{align}
E(x,y) &=  \int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-x/s}}{s}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-ys)^n}{n!} \,\mathrm{d}s
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n y^n}{n!}\int_0^1 \mathrm{e}^{-x/s} s^{n-1}\,\mathrm{d}s\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n y^n}{n!}E_{n+1}(x).
\end{align}
This series, however, is rather poorly convergent when $y>1$. Can we do better?

Context: This integral arises in the Ewald summation technique for 1D-periodic systems embedded in a 2D coordinate system; in my case, $x$ and $y$ take values from $0$'ish to $10$'ish. Presently, I'm forced to evaluate the integral by numerical quadrature, which is painstakingly slow.

Comment: Dumb question on my part, but would taking Fourier or Laplace transforms help? Otherwise I have no ideas or suggestions; this is outside my area of expertise.

Comment: The integral itself actually enters as a Fourier coefficient in a separate sum, so I would be inclined to think that a Fourier/Laplace approach would not be too useful here.

Comment: Shoot, maybe you could try Monte Carlo integration?

Comment: This being a 1D integral, and Monte Carlo integration being advantageous primarily in multidimensional integration, I don't see why that would be particularly suited here? It seems to me that conventional adaptive quadrature should be preferable, if a numerical quadrature approach is pursued.

Comment: Special case: When $x = y$, $E(x,x) = K_0(2 x)$, where $K_0$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind.

Comment: That seems to be correct: indeed, that special case is itself an example of this anti-symmetric relation: $E(x,y) + E(y,x) = 2K_0(2\sqrt{xy})$, which can be be derived with the help of the integral listed in Gradsteyn & Ryzhik's Eq. 3.471.9. It seems hard to generalize further though, or even to utilize it for approximate evaluation?

Comment: That would be hard to know for certain without testing such an algorithm in practice.

Comment: For the hell of it, I'll add that the technique of "integration under the integral sign" leads to the conclusion that $E(x,y)=−x^{-1}\Big(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\int_0^1 \mathrm{e}^{−tx/s−ys}\,\mathrm{d}s\Big)\Big|_{t=1}$. In other words, the above problem is in a sense solved if the integral $\int_0^1 \mathrm{e}^{−tx/s−ys}\,\mathrm{d}s$ can be obtained; unfortunately, that appears equally challenging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_0^1\dfrac{e^{-\frac{x}{s}-ys}}{s}~ds$

$=\int_\infty^1se^{-xs-\frac{y}{s}}~d\left(\dfrac{1}{s}\right)$

$=\int_1^\infty\dfrac{e^{-xs-\frac{y}{s}}}{s}~ds$

$=K_0(x,y)$ (according to https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81935301.pdf)

Comment: Ah, now that is a useful observation; now there's a name for it - incomplete Bessel funcitons; I never knew such a generalization existed! That should make it significantly easier to look for fast numerical implementations of this function. Thank you!